# Find a third degree polynomial $p(x)$ such that the function $f$ is continuously differentiable

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, continuity

Function $f$ is defined piecewise as follows:

$$
f = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad x<-1 \\
            p(x) & \quad -1\le x\le1 \\
            e^{-4(x-1)} & \quad x>1 \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Find a third degree polynomial $p(x)$ such that the function $f$ is continuously differentiable.

$$ p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0 $$

This is what I have tried this far.

Lets call the functions:
$$ h(x)=1 , x<-1$$
$$ g(x)=e^{-4(x-1)},x>1$$

I calculated the limits:
$$\lim_{x \to -1^-} h(x)= 1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} g(x)=\lim_{x \to 1^+} e^{-4(x-1)}=1$$

Next I calculate $p(1)=1$ and $p(−1)=1$
$$p(1)=a_3+a_2+a_1+a_0 = 1$$
$$p(-1)=-a_3+a_2-a_1+a_0 = 1$$

I get:
$$a_3+a_2x+a_1+a_0 + (-a_3+a_2-a_1+a_0) \Rightarrow 2a_2+2a_0=2 $$

Next I calculate the derivatives:
$$ p'(x)=3a_3x^2+2a_2x+a_1 $$
$$ h'(x)=0 $$
$$ g'(x)=-4e^{-4(x-1)}$$

Next the I calculate $p'(-1) = h'(-1)$ and $p'(1) = g'(1)$:
$$3a_3-2a_2+a_1 = 0$$
$$3a_3+2a_2+a_1 = -4$$

I get:
$$6a_3+2a_1=-4$$

Next I calculate the second order derivatives:
$$ p''(x)=6a_3x+2a_2$$
$$ h''(x)=0 $$
$$ g''(x)=16e^{-4(x-1)}$$

Next the I calculate $p''(-1) = h''(-1)$ and $p''(1) = g''(1)$:
$$ -6a_3+2a_2=0$$
$$6a_3+2a_2=16$$
$$ \Rightarrow 4a_2=16\Rightarrow a_2=4$$

Next the I calculate $p'''(-1) = h'''(-1)$ and $p'''(1) = g'''(1)$:
$$ 6a_3=0$$
$$6a_3=-64$$
$$ \Rightarrow 12a_3=-64\Rightarrow a_3=-\frac{16}{3}$$

Now I can solve $a_0$ from the previous result $2a_2+2a_0=2$:
$$2(4)+2a_0=2\Rightarrow a_0=-3$$

I can solve $a_1$ from the previous result $6a_3+2a_1=-4$:
$$6(-\frac{16}{3})+2a_1=-4\Rightarrow a_1=14$$

Hence:
$a_3 = -\frac{16}{3}\\a_2 =4\\a_1 =14\\a_0 =-3$

Edit: I found the answer. I will post it later today. In short, it was a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Have you done questions on continuity before? Here, for example you'd have to examine the situations at $-1$ and $1$, so what should $p(1)$ and $p(-1)$ be, is the first thing you should ask.

Comment: Yes. This far I have calculated $p(1) = 1$ and $p(-1)=1, p'(1) =0$ and $p(-1)=-4$ etc,. and from there tried to solve the constant terms. Is this the right path?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So there are four conditions  for four variables, this should be forcing $p$ to be unique.

Comment: By the way, if you find anything extra about the problem, like how you found these constants, do edit the post and reflect your working . This will allow people to work from where you finished or got stuck, and/or explain why you got stuck. This will also ensure that you get good answers on this site. I'm very happy that you have written in MathJax, however. Other people looking at this question should feel it is complete, so that's why I'm asking you to be a little particular in this regard. Of course, we will answer your question as well. You can see my edits on your question, thanks!

Comment: Just seen the edits. I will give you a +1 for your effort. If the answer's wrong, then we will see to it that it is corrected.

Comment: It should be $p'(-1) = 0$ and $p'(1) = -4$.

Comment: Yes, I apologize there's a typo. Thank you anyhow

Comment: Hi! Since you have found the solution, you may want to post that as an answer, not an edit to your question. After some time, you may also want to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

The function can be extended to be continuously differentiable with a polynomial by requiring it to satisfy the following conditions:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x \to 1}p(x)&=&\lim_{x  \to 1+}f(x)\\
\lim_{x \to -1}p(x)&=&\lim_{x  \to -1-}f(x)\\
\lim_{x \to 1}p'(x)&=&\lim_{x  \to 1+}f'(x)\\
\lim_{x \to -1}p'(x)&=&\lim_{x  \to -1-}f'(x).
\end{eqnarray}

Now it holds that

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&{\frac{1}{e^{4\,\left(x-1\right)}}}\\
f'(x)&=&{-\frac{4}{e^{4\,\left(x-1\right)}}}.
\end{eqnarray}

In order to determine the multipliers of the polynomial, we form a system of equations.

\begin{eqnarray}
a_3\cdot 1^3+a_2\cdot 1^2+a_1\cdot 1+a_0&=&f(1)\nonumber\\
a_3\cdot (-1)^3+a_2\cdot (-1)^2+a_1\cdot (-1)+a_0&=&f(-1)\nonumber\\
3\cdot a_3\cdot 1^2+2\cdot a_2\cdot 1+a_1&=&f'(1)\nonumber\\
3\cdot a_3\cdot (-1)^2+2\cdot a_2\cdot (-1)+a_1&=&f'(-1)\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

Finally, we express the system of equations in matrix form and solve the constants.

$$
{\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & -2 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_3 \\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\ 
a_0
\end{bmatrix} ={\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ -4 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_3 \\
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_0
\end{bmatrix} ={\left[\begin{array}{c} -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{array}\right]}
$$

Thus

$$
p(x)=-x^3-x^2+x+2
$$